# Sending data between 2 TCP apps through physical loopback. Will it go through NIC?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking

What is the data actual path if I run 2 applications sending/receiving data using sockets through TCP loopback? Will this data go through Windows network driver and/or NIC hardware?

*EDIT. Please consider this is not Windows 'loopback' but physical loopback made on the NIC with 2 ports connected with a cable to each other making it physical loopback.*

Comment: It would be at the network driver level.  The hardware likely would never see any of the packets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loopback is a *virtual* interface, there's no hardware corresponding to it. Data copy happens inside the kernel even above the driver level.

#### Edit 0:

You are mixing two different things - [*loopback*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loopback) in TCP/IP is a virtual network interface with a special address in subnet `127/8`, usually `127.0.0.1`, which is created for you by default, and ethernet [*crossover*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) cable looping between two cards on the same machine.

I addressed the first case in my initial answer.

The behavior of the TCP/IP stack in the second case depends on the implementation and the transport options. For a TCP connection and for unicast UDP the kernel might just realize that both source and target addresses are local to the machine and short-circuit data transfer through memory. You'll find that most modern network stacks behave this way. For broadcast or multicast UDP there's no other option but to send packets through physical card since there might be other listeners on the network.

Comment: Nikolai, could you please explain. If I have a card with 2 interfaces and I set 2 different IPs on each and then connect one interface with another creating a physical loopback, and then I run 2 apps where sokects will be attached to these 2 different APIs... Do you think traffic will be coming through virtual loopback provided by Windows and not the NIC itself?